# Mat-Select does not apply the default design pattern

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a simple mat-select and this is how i specify my code in one of my components:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select>
        <mat-option>First Option</mat-option>
        <mat-option>Second Option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
 </mat-form-field>
```

This is what my app.component.ts looks like:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { MatToolbarModule } from "@angular/material/toolbar";
import { KniffelComponent } from "./components/kniffel/kniffel.component";
import { MatButtonModule } from "@angular/material/button";
import { MatDividerModule } from "@angular/material/divider";
import { MatListModule } from "@angular/material/list";
import { MatSelectModule } from "@angular/material/select";
import { MatFormFieldModule } from "@angular/material/form-field";
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, KniffelComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I tried to recompile etc. already, it unfortunately does not change anything. Here is the output of the ng --version command:

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.4
Node: 12.13.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.900.4
@angular-devkit/core         9.0.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.0.4
@schematics/angular          9.0.4
@schematics/update           0.900.4
rxjs                         6.5.3
```

I do not get an compiler-error or anything like that, it just simply does not look like it looks on the in the official documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview . I would have added images to show what visualize what the problem is, but this beeing a new account prevents me from doing so... If anybody has any idea what i could have done wrong or what the problem might be, i would be happy to try out some solutions! Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: have you added default css in angular.json file or style.css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

angular material needs some predefined theme to work properly, one of the predefined themes is "deeppurple-amber". open style css and include following line

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

you can read more info here
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming